# MySQL - Delete Rows Not Being Used

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `events` and `locations`.  Each has a column named `venue_id` to match an event to the correct location.  `venue_id` is not the primary key.

What query could I run to delete the rows in `locations` that have no event linked to them?

Comment: We need to see more of the table structure to be able to help you.

Comment: Do you mean where venue_id is null in the locations table, or where a foreign key to the events table doesn't exist? I'm not entirely sure based on your question. Showing your schema might help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it :

```
DELETE FROM locations WHERE venue_id
NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT venue_id FROM events)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
DELETE FROM Locations where venue_id not in
  (select distinct venue_id from Events);
```